# Javascript response and ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, es6-promise

I have the following:

```
function wikiAjax (searchURL) {
    return Promise.resolve($.ajax({
        url: searchURL,
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
    }));
}

$(".search-form").submit(function() {
    var searchText = $('#search').val();
    var searchURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=" + searchText + "&gsrlimit=15&prop=extracts&exsentences=3&exintro=&explaintext&exlimit=max&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    console.log(searchURL);
    var wikiResponse = wikiAjax(searchURL);
    wikiResponse.then(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }, function() {
        alert("The call has been rejected");
    });
});
```

But i get an answer only if I put a breakpoint somewhere (e.g. at the `wikiResponse.then` line).

Then it looks like the code is executed before the call returns the result but why? Isn't the promise set properly?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think the code is executed before the call returns?

Comment: @JesseLee because if i put a breakpoint i can see the object in the alert.

Answer (score 4):

I think what might be happening here is the browser is executing the default submit event on the form in addition to the ajax call.  The result is that the window is unloaded and reloaded.

Try putting:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in the handler.

```
$(".search-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchText = $('#search').val();
    var searchURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=" + searchText + "&gsrlimit=15&prop=extracts&exsentences=3&exintro=&explaintext&exlimit=max&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    console.log(searchURL);
    var wikiResponse = wikiAjax(searchURL);
    wikiResponse.then(function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    function() {
      alert("The call has been rejected");
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: So, if you create a form with a submit button, by default the browser will handle that submit event by navigating to the 'action' for that form.  Presumably you have no action supplied as an attribute in the <form> element so the browser will use the current URL as the form action.  The result will essentially be a page refresh.  Since the page was refreshing before your ajax call returned it basically got canceled.  By preventing the browser's default handler with e.preventDefault() you stop the browser from refreshing the page.

Comment: Your welcome!  Would you mark it as the approved answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to do Promise.resolve here, because the $.ajax call already returns a promise. 
 Try this:

```
function wikiAjax (searchURL) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: searchURL,
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
}

$(".search-form").submit(function() {
    var searchText = $('#search').val();
    var searchURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=" + searchText + "&gsrlimit=15&prop=extracts&exsentences=3&exintro=&explaintext&exlimit=max&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    console.log(searchURL);
    var wikiResponse = wikiAjax(searchURL);
    wikiResponse.done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }).fail(function(err) {
        alert("The call has been rejected");
    });
});
```

This is a working (and modified to show) plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qyc4Tu1waQO6EspomMYL?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @pkeuter but with your solution it doesn't work, even with the breakpoint.

Comment: @S4rg0n Have you looked at the plnkr? It surely does work, so you must be doing something else differently. As mentioned above, are you using a recent version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I think Promise.resolve() is an ES6 feature so unless you explicitly make sure you support it it should not work.

But, lucky for you $.ajax() return a promise in the following format:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
  url: "/myServerScript"
});

promise.done(mySuccessFunction);
promise.fail(myErrorFunction);
```

(and not with then() and catch() like was written in your code)

Comment: Thank you @chenop but it behaves exactly the same

Comment: what JQuery version you use?

Comment: i have 2,2,2. Jesse Lee solution worked, the problem was with the form submit :-) Thank you!